# How to compile llvm?

Tags: compilation, llvm

In order to compile some software, I need to get llvm. I'm on Arch Linux (Manjaro), latest kernel version, and I'm trying to compile llvm. I have one issue: my CPU seems to overload, and compilation either crashes or take forever for one step (I left compilation running for 8 hours and 8 steps out of 3000 were done). How can I get llvm? I'm really confused.

Comment: Reduce the number of parallel jobs. See older questions.

Answer (score 0):

As arnt said, just had to reduce the number of parallel jobs.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).